# list out paired bluetooth devices in listview created in layout

Tags: android, xcode, bluetooth, helper, core-bluetooth

I want to list out all the paired devices in a list that i created in layouts.. what wrong in this code? i just created this function to display all the bonded devices

```
void tooth_scan() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pairList);
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    devicesPaired = new String[pairedDevices.size()];
    int count = 0;
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            devicesPaired[count] = device.getName();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                devicesPaired);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any exception or it isn't showing any entry?

Comment: @waqas nope if i call this function then the app just stops working giving a error message

Comment: when your apps fails, it should generate some info in logcat, post those logcats here

Comment: I have modified the code how to comment it?

Comment: And I am getting this info in logcat

Comment: how to comment it here its too long

Comment: 03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at com.pc.touchpad.StartBluetooth.pairedTooth(StartBluetooth.java:93)

Comment: 03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at com.pc.touchpad.StartBluetooth$2.onClick(StartBluetooth.java:99)
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 17:33:40.170: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: I guess u are getting exception in bAdapter.getBondedDevices(); method

Comment: Hey sorry I dint added it the activity in manifest .xml Thanks allot for your replies :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public void showPairedDevices()
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> bluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                String deviceName = device.getName(); // Get BT name
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress(); // Get MAC
                ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.paired_list);

                bluetoothDevices.add(deviceName);

                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,bluetoothDevices);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you use Set as you need get distinct devices, otherwise you will get duplicate list. All the best